# I want to make a sql query to get distinct products data having attributes in separate table

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables I have:

1. Products (id, title)

[1, 'Old car'], [2, 'New car'], [3, 'Future car'])

2. Attributes (id, name)

[1, 'brand'], [2, 'model'], [3, 'color']

3. Attribute_values (attribute_id, product_id, value)

[1, 1, 'toyota'], [1, 2, 'honda'], [1, 3, 'ford'], [1, 3, 'red'], [2, 3, 'white'], [3, 3, 'red']

I tried query:

```
select p.*, a.name as attribute_name, av.value as attribute_value from attributes as a 
join attribute_values as av on a.id=av.attribute_id
join products as p on av.product_id=p.id
where
((a.name='brand' and av.value='toyota') or (a.name='color' and av.value='red'))
```

It gives each row matching the or query condition.

Eg:

- [id:1, title:'Old car', attribute_name:'brand',
  attribute_value:'toyota']
- [id:1, title:'Old car', attribute_name:'color',
  attribute_value:'red']
- [id:3, title:'Future car', attribute_name:'color',
  attribute_value:'red']

**Here, results found are: 'Old car' and 'Future car', but I need 'Old car' not 'Future car'.**

**Can this be done with single query?**

Comment: What exactly is the result you want to have?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if your records that you have mentioned are proper. Because for Attribute "model" you have mentioned as "white" for "new Car". This is with respect to Attribute_values  table

Comment: Incidentally, and not that it makes any difference, but we would normally place the entity (product) column at the beginning of an EAV table.

Comment: @Simone yes, product relation to an attribute is saved in Attribute_values table

Comment: @Strawberry I did not understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this query. The original query output 1 row when records matches 1 of your criteria.
From the result, we check the same `product id` whether having 2 records in the results. If yes, meaning 2 criterias (brand = `Toyota` & color = `red`) are matched for same `product`.

```
SELECT id as product_id, count(attribute_name) as attribute_count FROM
(
    select 
        p.*, 
        a.name as attribute_name, 
        av.value as attribute_value

    from products as p 
        join attribute_values as av
            on p.id = av.product_id
        join attributes as a 
            on a.id = av.attribute_id

    where
        (a.name='brand' and av.value='toyota')
        or (a.name='color' and av.value='red')

) a

GROUP BY a.id
HAVING (attribute_count = 2);
```

SQL Fiddle link for test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab857a/2

**Edit:**

On the other hand, you may also try this `second approach`. First we do 2 separate `subselect` to get product which matches each of the 2 criterias. Then we `JOIN` the subselects together to get products that match both criteria:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.attribute_2,
    b.value_2

FROM
(
    SELECT 
        p.*, 
        a.name as attribute_1, 
        av.value as value_1
    FROM
        products as p
        JOIN attribute_values as av 
            ON av.product_id = p.id
        JOIN attributes as a
            ON a.id = av.attribute_id
    WHERE
        a.name = 'brand'
        and av.value = 'toyota'
) a

JOIN

(
    SELECT 
        p.*, 
        a.name as attribute_2, 
        av.value as value_2
    FROM
        products as p
        JOIN attribute_values as av 
            ON av.product_id = p.id
        JOIN attributes as a
            ON a.id = av.attribute_id
    WHERE
        a.name = 'color'
        and av.value = 'red'
) b

ON a.id = b.id
```

SQL Fiddle code sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b836d/1

Comment: It's not my downvote, but those really need to be left joins

Comment: @Strawberry, As he is looking for both conditions (brand toyota & red color) to be matched, so it has to be `JOIN`, not `left join`. Unless I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the records in your attribute_value table as follows assuming this is correct:

```
attribute_id  |   product_id   |   value
------------------------------------------
1         |       1        |   toyota
1         |       2        |   honda
1         |       3        |   ford
3         |       1        |   red
3         |       2        |   white
3         |       3        |   red
```

and I have modified your query as follows:

```
select p.*, a.name as attribute_name, av.value as attribute_value from attributes as a 
    join attribute_values as av on a.id=av.attribute_id
    join products as p on av.product_id=p.id
    where
        (
            if(a.name='brand',av.value='toyota',0) 
      or if(a.name='color',av.value='red',0)
     ) 
GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(av.attribute_id) =2
```

Here **"2"** should be dynamic based on how many attributes you are filtering with. Since in your example you have filtered with 2 attributes, I have mentioned 2

Fiddle is present at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6ff9/2